# How to square a bi-infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose any real number $R$ can be represented as bi-infinite series

$$\begin{aligned}
R=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} D_i \cdot 10^i
\end{aligned}$$

For example, $R=12.34$ can be represented as:

$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} D_i \cdot 10^i = \overbrace{\dots + 0\cdot10^2 + 1\cdot10^1 + 2\cdot10^0}^{\text{integer part}} + \underbrace{3\cdot10^{-1} + 4\cdot10^{-2} + 0\cdot10^{-3} + \dots}_{\text{fractional part}}
\end{aligned}$

Is this a correct method to square a bi-infinite series?

$$\begin{aligned}
R^2 &=\left(\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} D_i \cdot 10^i\right)^2\\
&= \left(\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} D_i \cdot 10^i\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} D_j \cdot 10^j\right) \\
&= \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} D_i D_j \cdot 10^{i+j} \\
&= \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} (D_i \cdot 10^i)^2 + 2 \cdot \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{j=-\infty, j\neq i}^{\infty} (D_i \cdot D_j \cdot 10^{i+j})
\end{aligned}$$

The last expression is based upon this [rule](https://planetmath.org/squareofsum#:%7E:text=The%20square%20of%20a%20sum,jaiaj.)

> The square of a sum is equal to the sum of the squares of all the
> summands plus the sum of all the double products of the summands in
> twos:

$$\begin{aligned}
\left(\sum_{i}a_{i}\right)^{2}\;=\;\sum_{i}a_{i}^{2}+2\!\sum_{i<j}a_{i}a_{j}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: The simple answer is that it will depend on how you defined products on bi-infinite series (and why you are looking at bi-infinite series). I am not aware of a common enough useage that there is a consensus. As long as your definition is sensible it will be fine. There is consesus on how to define products on both left and right infinite series (for left infinte look into p-adic numbers, and right infinite is just standard products on real numbers) however I cannot see how you could make the two work together, as one assumes nothing gets very big and the other assumes nothing gets very small.

Comment: Following up on @Fishbane's comment: if you really are dealing with real numbers, then they are infinite series to the right but only finite series to the left (they can be arbitrarily long to the left but not infinite), and thus ordinary multiplication of one-sided series works just fine.